# Delimiter to split Bash function arguments as an array of strings

Tags: arrays, bash, delimiter, ifs

For a Bash function `my_fun`, how can I use a delimiter (e.g. ";") to split input into an array of strings?

Example input:

```
$ my_fun This is ; an example
```

Example output:

```
string1: This is
string2: an example
```

Perhaps using `$IFS=';'` or the `read` command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Comment: It's close, but the input needs to be the parameters of a function. I intend to use it to create SQL queries.

Comment: `;` is not a good choice. it's a command separator in the shell

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That may have been the cause of my problem.

Comment: You'll probably have to quote the parameter no matter what you choose as a delimiter. This can be messy if the parameter also *contains* quotes, because quotes of the same type don't nest (i.e. you can't put single-quotes in a single-quoted string without gymnastics, and double-quotes must be escaped inside double-quotes).

Comment: See: [How to be explicit about intentional word splitting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62638388/7939871)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop, no need to `read`, simply assign an array with `IFS` set to `;`:

```bash
my_fun() { IFS=';' arr=( $@ ); printf '|%s|\n' "${arr[@]}"; }
my_fun "foo ; bar ; baz"
|foo |
| bar |
| baz|
```

As noted in comments this may break if the input contains glob patterns (like `*`): pathname expansion would apply. If this can happen you can enable/disable the `noglob` option:

```bash
my_fun() { set -f; IFS=';' arr=( $@ ); set +f; printf '|%s|\n' "${arr[@]}"; }
```

Comment: I appreciate that this is the most minimal approach, and it isolates the task more neatly than I had in my question. Thank you!

Comment: This may break if glob chars are present (eg. `my_fun '*'` in a directory containing some non-hidden files).

Comment: @rowboat You're absolutely right. Added this and suggested `noglob`.

Answer (score 2):

Delimiter `;` needs to be escaped with a backslash (`\;`) to prevent Bash from interpreting it as a command separator :

```bash
my_fun() {
  IFS=';' read -ra arr <<< "$@"
  for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    echo "string$i: ${arr[i]}"
  done
}
```

Output :

```
$ my_fun This is\;an example
string0: This is
string1: an example
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the comments, here's my solution:

```
split_str() {
    IFS=";" read -ra arr <<< "$*"
    s1="${arr[0]}"
    s2="${arr[1]}"
    echo "s1: $s1"
    echo "s2: $s2"
}
```

Example:

```
$ split_str "This is;a test"
s1: This is
s2: a test
```

The parameters are to be quoted, so it doesn't matter whether the delimiter is a command separator in the shell.